# Error: rendered more hooks than previous render

Tags: reactjs, api

Hello everyone am getting this error while connecting 2 queries eachother.

```
function App(){
  let boardId = GetBoard(window.location.pathname);
  if(boardId !== undefined){
    console.log(boardId);
  }

  let tickets = GetTickets(boardId);
  if( tickets !== undefined){
    
    console.log(tickets);
  }
  
  //return codes
}
```

That is my app function in app.js

```
export function GetTickets(boardID){
const [data, setData] = useState();


const getTickets = () => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("request","getTickets");
  data.append("boardID",boardID);
  fetch("http://localhost/api.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setData(data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTickets();
  },[]);

  return( 
    data
  );
}
```

And this is my GetTickets function. I use same logic on GetBoard function.

When I call this functions seperately there is no error but if I put **boardId** variable in to GetTickets function it gives this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
    at updateWorkInProgressHook (react-dom.development.js:16507:1)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16568:1)
    at updateState (react-dom.development.js:17004:1)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17915:1)
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at GetTickets (GetTickets.js:4:1)
    at App (App.js:47:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` hook should be inside the component function and not inside the nested function

```
export function GetTickets(boardID){
const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  getTickets();
},[]);

const getTickets = () => {
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("request","getTickets");
  data.append("boardID",boardID);
  fetch("http://localhost/api.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setData(data));
  };
  return( 
    data
  );
}
```

Comment: I did not get it can you please help me I am newbie on react :(

Comment: This `return data` doesn't` do anything and you don't return any jsx, but other than that it's done